# Getting a token for Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, thinktecture-ident-model

Once upon a time I used to install `Thinktecture.IdentityModel`, call it using basic auth to get a token and then pass this in the headers of ajax calls to Web API.

I just tried to do this, and it barfed.

### Up periscope!

Method not found: no match for ctor signature (hurrah for Fiddler).

Comparison with a project in which it *does* work reveals that the required signature exists in version 2.0.0.0 of `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` but is no longer present in version 4.0.20622.1351

### Quick, Robin - to the Bingpole!

There's a github support query [on this very topic](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/issues/97) and in the comments we find

> **leastprivilege  commented on Jan 27**
>
> The AuthenticationHandler is not the recommended approach anymore for
>   Web API v2 since everything is now built-in - use middleware instead.

### Unask the question, Grasshopper

This is a definitive opinion. He's one of the library's authors. It is also incredibly unhelpful to anyone who needs to ask the question.

Could someone could point me at appropriate introductory and tutorial links so I can join the ranks of those who nod sagely and marvel at the zen-like brevity of this comment?

I was using AuthenticationHandler to validate out of SQL Server table containing a username and password. Purists please don't lecture me, there are countless businesses that don't or won't use third party OAUTH. I need to convert a username/password pair into a session token that I can use on my Web API methods. That's all. I happen to agree about OAUTH but the people paying for this are not interested in grand unified authentication, they *like* silos.

### Supplementary info

I found a [publically accessible PluralSight course](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/player?author=dominick-baier&name=webapi-v2-security-m3-architecture&mode=live&clip=0&course=webapi-v2-security) on the whole authentication thing. It's by the fellow who wrote the ThinkTecture.AuthenticationHandler and it's quite good as a backgrounder on recent change.

In the course of the material he refers to [another PluralSight course on MVC](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m1-introduction&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals), which has more [information on OWIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Web_Interface_for_.NET) (which is pure API ie an interface) and [Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana) (which is Microsoft's implementation of OWIN).

At this point it is clear to me that

- There has been a fundamental architecture change for assorted good reasons.
- A `MessageHandler` is not the place to do authentication.
- There is a NuGet package called Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.BasicAuthentication which is described as OWIN middleware for HTTP Basic Authentication in OWIN/Katana applications.

My still fuzzy understanding of the new landscape suggests that the middleware package is what I need. NuGet did its thing and now I have to provide some code to insert the middleware into the OWIN middleware chain and more code to actually validate the credentials. As near as I can tell I need to do this in Startup.Auth.cs

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
  app.UseBasicAuthentication("some_realm", (id, secret) =>
  {
    if (id == secret) //should check database, but never mind right now
    {
      var claims = new List<Claim> {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, id),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Foo") //this can come from db also
      };
      return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Claim>>(claims);
    }
    return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Claim>>(null);
  });
```

Assuming I've got this right so far, how do I use it? Do I continue to decorate Web API methods with `[Authorize]`?

### Success! Nearly.

At the moment a request from my test client causes a hit on the breakpoint I've set on the line `if (id == secret)` and the condition is satisfied because id and secret contain the values sent by my test code. Claims objects are created as per the code above and duly returned, but the test client receives 401 Unauthorized.

This is almost certainly due to a failure to create a principal object. There's some business with a UserManager and an IdentityModel, and it may be possible to customise that to use our own schema.